# Смена параметров кнопки angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Добрый вечер. Не получается сделать смену цвета и текста кнопки при нажатии. От сервера приходит булеан, в зависимости от его значение выводится определенная кнопка.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in allEmployee">
    <td>
        <button style="width:80px;height:35px" ng-click="changeEmployeeStatus(employee)" ng-class="{'btn btn-success' : employee.active, 'btn btn-danger' : !employee.active}"
                type="button">{{employee.active? 'Active': 'UnActive'}}
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии вызывалась не только функция `changeEmployeeStatus(employee)`, но и менялся цвет и надпись кнопки?

changeEmployeeStatus(employee):

Контроллер:

```
$scope.changeEmployeeStatus = function (employee) {
    staffManagementService.changeEmployeeStatus(employee.email).success(function   (data) {
          console.log(data);
    });
};
```

сервис:

```
service.changeEmployeeStatus = function (email) {
    console.log(email)
    http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/admin/changeEmployeeStatus',
        params : {email:email}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
            return data;
    });
};
```

Comment: а чем не устраивает текущее решение?

Comment: Сейчас цвет и текст поменяется только после перезагрузки страницы(данные из бд подтянутся). А мне надо чтоб они менялись сразу при нажатии.

Comment: что из себя представляет _changeEmployeeStatus_? приведите ее код. А так же какое значение имеет myClass?

Comment: changeEmployeeStatus лезет в бд и меняет значение статуса заданого емплоера. Возвращается булеан. Код добавил в первый пост. И еще я не много обновил код кнопки, сделал его более читаемым. Извините что сразу не сказал.

Comment: Но вопрос смены цвета и текста остается открытым.

Comment: судя по всему данный код должен падать на строке `staffManagementService.changeEmployeeStatus(employee.email).success`, так как функция `service.changeEmployeeStatus` ничего не возвращает, стоит проверить консоль браузера

Comment: там действительно вылетает ошибка, но суть не в этом). Запрос в бд доходит, меняет статус, и если обновить страницу то можно увидеть что кнопка работает(цвет поменялся, текст тоже). но мне нужно чтоб она сразу менялась (без обновления страницы).

Comment: Ну это одна из двух ошибок :-) так что в принципе можно сказать что суть в этом тоже :)

Comment: поменять вызов сервисной функции в контроллере на что-то вроде 

$scope.changeEmployeeStatus = function (employee) {
        staffManagementService.changeEmployeeStatus(employee.email);
    };

?

Comment: добавил ответ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае view зависит от значения поля `active` в объекте `employee`, но так как ни в одной из функций оно не меняется - отображение не обновляется.

Для решения нужно заполнить это поле результатом запроса

```
$scope.changeEmployeeStatus = function (employee) {
    staffManagementService.changeEmployeeStatus(employee.email).success(function   (data) {
          employee.active = data;
    });
};
```

Кроме того необходимо добавить `return` в функцию сервера, чтобы избежать обращения к *undefined* в контроллере

```
service.changeEmployeeStatus = function (email) {
    console.log(email)
    return http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/admin/changeEmployeeStatus',
        params : {email:email}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Извините, я что-то туплю уже. с обеда сижу. Спасибо большое!!)Все работает!